# Rails Subdomain for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, subdomain, rails-routing

I've got a Rails 4 app that I'm trying to reconfigure to use subdomains for `jobportals`. Right now the root path for each portal is `/jobportals/:id`. What I want is for a user to be able to go to `client.example.com` and hit that root path. Then for example, if the user edits their profile, the url would be `client.example.com/user/edit` rather than `www.example.com/jobportals/:id/user/edit`.

I followed [this ASCIIcasts tutorial](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3) on setting up subdomain routing, but it's not working for me. When I go to `http://client.lvh.me:3000/`, I am hitting the `root_path` of my Rails app, rather than the `root_path` for the portal.

I think the problem is that `Constraints(Subdomain)` isn't working with `resources :jobportals`. How can I reconfigure my routes to accomplish what I'm after?

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
    root 'general#home'

    get '/about' => 'general#about'
    get '/team' => 'general#team'
    get '/careers' => 'general#careers'
    get '/terms' => 'general#terms'
    get '/privacy_policy' => 'general#privacy_policy'

    constraints(Subdomain) do
        resources :jobportals, controller: 'portals/general' do
            member do
                root 'portals/general#home'
                devise_scope :user do
                    get '/user/sign_in' => 'portals/sessions#new'
                    post '/user/sign_in' => 'portals/sessions#create'
                    delete '/user/sign_out' => 'portals/sessions#destroy'
                    post '/user/password' => 'portals/passwords#create'
                    get '/user/password/new' => 'portals/passwords#new'
                    get '/user/password/edit' => 'portals/passwords#edit'
                    patch '/user/password' => 'portals/passwords#update'
                    put '/user/password' => 'portals/passwords#update'

                    post '/user' => 'portals/registrations#create'
                    get '/user/sign_up' => 'portals/registrations#new'
                    get '/user/edit' => 'portals/registrations#edit'
                    patch '/user' => 'portals/registrations#update'
                    put '/user' => 'portals/registrations#update'
                    delete '/user' => 'portals/registrations#destroy'
                end

                get '/jobs' => 'portals/general#jobs'
                get '/companies' => 'portals/general#companies'
                get '/alljobs' => 'portals/general#alljobs'

                resources :applications, controller: 'portals/applications'

                get ':id' => 'portals/companies#profile'
                get ':id/jobs' => 'portals/companies#jobs'
                get ':id/jobfunctions' => 'portals/companies#jobfunctions'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

**Working Code Below**

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
    root 'general#home'

    get '/about' => 'general#about'
    get '/team' => 'general#team'
    get '/careers' => 'general#careers'
    get '/terms' => 'general#terms'
    get '/privacy_policy' => 'general#privacy_policy'

    constraints(Subdomain) do
        get '/' => 'portals/general#home'
        devise_scope :user do
            get '/user/sign_in' => 'portals/sessions#new'
            post '/user/sign_in' => 'portals/sessions#create'
            delete '/user/sign_out' => 'portals/sessions#destroy'
            post '/user/password' => 'portals/passwords#create'
            get '/user/password/new' => 'portals/passwords#new'
            get '/user/password/edit' => 'portals/passwords#edit'
            patch '/user/password' => 'portals/passwords#update'
            put '/user/password' => 'portals/passwords#update'

            post '/user' => 'portals/registrations#create'
            get '/user/sign_up' => 'portals/registrations#new'
            get '/user/edit' => 'portals/registrations#edit'
            patch '/user' => 'portals/registrations#update'
            put '/user' => 'portals/registrations#update'
            delete '/user' => 'portals/registrations#destroy'
        end

        get '/jobs' => 'portals/general#jobs'
        get '/companies' => 'portals/general#companies'
        get '/alljobs' => 'portals/general#alljobs'

        resources :applications, controller: 'portals/applications'

        get ':id' => 'portals/companies#profile'
        get ':id/jobs' => 'portals/companies#jobs'
        get ':id/jobfunctions' => 'portals/companies#jobfunctions'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is looking like constraints are not define properly, it is something like `get 'jobportals', constraints: {subdomain: 'subdomain_name'}`
    [Checkout the rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints)

Comment: It turns out that I needed to get rid of my `resources: :jobportals` and `member do` blocks. I then moved my `Constraints(Subdomain)` block to the top of my routes file, which was the key. If I keep it a the bottom, all requests to `/` get intercepted by `root_path`, even if there is a subdomain. If I move `root_path` and all other routes below my `Constraints(Subdomain)` block, `root_path` still works for the main app, but requests to `/` and all other routes for subdomains work properly. I updated my question with the working route structure.

Comment: I also tested your answer and it didn't work because you need to specify the controller for a `get` action and I'm pretty sure you can't call `get 'some_resource'`. I'm pretty sure it has to be `get '/some_route`.